# Unwanted space after \NewDocumentCommand vs. \newcommand

Tags: macros, spacing, xparse

I am trying to markup certain words in my text and automatically commit them to the index, with the option to modify the index entry. The `\newcommand` approach was not satisfying, as I did not manage to set the default value of the first argument to be the second.

With `\NewDocumentCommand` I managed to set the options properly, but it introduced an unwanted space when followed by punctuation. Can anyone explain, why this occurs and how to fix it?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
 


\newcommand{\neuold}[2][]{{\sffamily\textbf{ #2}}\index{#1 #2}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\neu}{m O{#1}}
{
\IfNoValueTF{#2}
{{\sffamily\textbf{#1}}}
{\sffamily\textbf{ #1}\index{ #2}}
}

\begin{document}
blabla  \neu{test}, blabla \neuold{test}, blabla
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well you have various spaces in your definition at the end of lines.

Comment: You are missing two % signs in your `\NewDocumentCommand`. It should be `…O#1}}{%… \index{ #2}}%`

Comment: Thanks to everybody for the quick and knowledgeable replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inserting spaces yourself.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\neu}{m O{#1}}
{% <--- space
\IfNoValueTF{#2}
{{\sffamily\textbf{#1}}}
{\sffamily\textbf{ #1}\index{ #2}}% <---
}
```

On the other hand, the `\IfNoValueTF` test will *always* return false, so it's useless. It's to be used with an `o` argument type. So

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\neu}{m O{#1}}
 {%
  \textsf{\textbf{#1}}\index{#2}%
 }
```

would be what you want. I see no reason for the space in front of `#1` and `#2`.

Answer (score 1):

The line feeds in the command are being expanded as spaces. You need to add `%` at the end of lines where you don't want a space to show up.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\neuold}[2][]{{\sffamily\textbf{ #2}}\index{#1 #2}}

\NewDocumentCommand{ \neu }{ m O{#1} }{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
    \sffamily\textbf{#1}%
  }{%
    \sffamily\textbf{#1}\index{#2}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
blabla  \neu{test}, blabla \neuold{test}, blabla \neu{test}[Test], blah
\end{document}
```